# How is this dividing by zero?

Tags: ruby, divide-by-zero

Really, really basic block in Ruby:

```
list = (1..125).to_a
list.each do |x|
    print x if 125 % x = 0
end
```

Gives me:

```
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
from (irb):3:in `%'
from (irb):3
from (irb):2:in `each'
from (irb):2
```

Yet the block "puts x" returns 1 through 125, just like it should.

What is going on?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're assigning 0 to x before the `%` operator is evaluated:

```
print x if 125 % x = 0
```

Note that the last bit, `x = 0`, is **assignment**. You need to use `==` to test for equality:

```
print x if 125 % x == 0
```

Comment: Aha! I figured it was something simple like that. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use `(125 % x).zero?` or even `125.modulo(x).zero?` to avoid problems like this one. BTW: since your problem is solved, you should probably accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You missed an `=`. Try to force evaluation order if it looks ambiguous:

`print x if (125 % x) == 0`